# How to implement git-like "branching" on a MongoDB database in Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, git, diff

I have another related question ([How to implement checking and ignoring when an array/object path is *moved* when diffing arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64635260/how-to-implement-checking-and-ignoring-when-an-array-object-path-is-moved-when)), but I also would like to know how to implement this system more generally.

Basically I am thinking of creating a "data editor" app, where I build a bunch of forms of various types, constructing all sorts of nested JSON (with array fields, nested array fields, etc.) in a generic MongoDB document. Say I end up having 1 million deeply nested JSON documents in this MongoDB collection (or perhaps many collections, I haven't decided yet). Say also there are 1000 people simultaneously editing these JSON fields ("paths" I'd call them, for reaching the deeply nested values in a JSON document). The high level question is how would I make this work like Git?

More specifically, the problem I'm imagining in my head can be solved by branching and creating "pull requests" on the data. This way people can essentially create a new branch of the entire database (like creating a git branch of the entire repo), and then edit whatever they want. Then using the diffing algorithm that I'm trying to figure out too (linked above), we could simply create a diff based on the "initial branch state" and the "final branch state". Then a PR would consist of a list of JSON "paths" and their corresponding values, which could then be approved and "merged" into the "main" MongoDB database.

How on earth would you begin architecting this?

- **How would you theoretically implement a complete MongoDB database "branching"?** It's not realistic to literally "clone" the database and every record, because the database might be several Gigabytes and too large to efficiently (time-wise and money-wise) clone. What would branching in this sort of system actually look like?

The reason I'm confused is mainly because say you have 2 people working on the same area of the database (same documents). Say they already clicked "create branch" and it didn't do anything literally to the database, but it will create a "diff container" to hold the diffs they create with the data, without actually modifying the original documents (until PR gets approved). This means that in order to fetch *their* view of the data, I need to fetch the original documents, plus their diffs, and merge them. Not too bad I guess. Is that all that needs to happen? Or am I missing something?

The problem is that, say person 2's PR gets approved in the middle of person 1 editing the similar data. Their view will now be changed because the main database is updated with new data they didn't do. How do I prevent this? **How would you literally branch a database**?

Comment: You wouldn't branch a database. You'd create an appropriate on-disk data storage system as git etc. have done.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are diving into the world of temporal data so it would probably help a lot to start drawing timelines.

Time:

```
----------------------------------------------->
```

Period of Validity:

```
         [------------)
```

Ongoing Validity:

```
         [------------------------------------->
```

Doc A created, and the most recent version is valid indefinitely:

```
         [------------------------------------->
```

Doc A forked:

```
         [------------------------------------->
User A Fork:            |---------------------->
```

Doc A forked again:

```
         [------------------------------------->
User A Fork:            |---------------------->
User B Fork:                   |--------------->
```

User A merges fork:

```
         [----------------------------)[------->
User A Fork:            |-------------^
User B Fork:                   |--------------->
```

User B has a copy of Doc A from a previous period of validity. Depending on how you want the application to behave, you may keep old versions of documents around so long as there is an active fork. Depending on the history requirements, you could prune off any documents whose period of validity is not ongoing AND has no active fork. [Here's a nice book about temporal sql databases that might interest you.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;?doi=10.1.1.636.6733&rep=rep1&type=pdf) Especially ch.2 and 5 about valid state.

I've never used it but maybe check out the source for [Irmin](https://irmin.org/) for more ideas.